# Laravel: Run command after server starts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am working in PHP and the Laravel framework.

I have a command I want to run when I am working locally.

```
    exec("start chrome.exe http://127.0.0.1:8000");
```

I only need this command to run once when the server is started

I have tried placing it in a few spots, but when I run `php artisan serve` google chrome opens new tabs until I stop the server.

Where is a safe place to place this command so it executes only once after the server has started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the `ServeCommand` class (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64fb6f745de496a2a114fdf896d3b60ab2119569/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php) and call your command in the `handle` method.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: This won't work outside of local development though, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think I would create a bash script or something similar to handle this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
# dev.sh
php artisan serve && chrome http://localhost:8000
```

Then you can just run `dev.sh` in your console.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I will have to do in in a bat file though lol. #windows